# F# Function with 'Matching' and 'Find and Replace'

Tags: f#, match, replace

I am struggling with creating a F# function.  I'm a novice (at best) with F# and really could use some help.  I've poured over this for a week, so any help you can provide is invaluable!

---

**Function Goals:**

- Inputs: a `List` and a `string`
- Revises the string to `Proper Case`
- Compares the string to each item in the list
- Replaces any matched item with the list item

  ---

**Example:**

- String = "the us dollar in sc"
- List   = ["NIF"; "PF"; "PS"; "SC"; "US"; "USA"; "USD"]

*Function actions:*

1. Sets the string to Proper Case= "The us dollar in sc"
2. Compares the string with each item in the list and replaces as appropriate

   - "us" becomes "US"
   - "sc" becomes "SC"
3. The final result is "The US dollar in SC"

This is what I have thus far.

```
let myList = ["NIF"; "PF"; "PS"; "SC"; "US"; "USA"; "USD"]
let FixAccronyms aList fixString= 
    aList |> List.iter 
        (fun listItem ->
        match listItem with            
        | fixString -> printfn  "%s, %s" listItem fixString
        | _ ->  printf  "%s" "" |> ignore)
```

In FSI:

> FixAccronyms myList "the us dollar in sc";;

The function iterates through the list, but it prints every item in the list, not just where it matches the fixString.  Assuming that worked, I am neither sure how to pattern match a portion of a string nor do a find and replace within the string...

---

**Results in FSI**

```
val myList2 : string list = ["NIF"; "PF"; "PS"; "SC"; "US"; "USA"; "USD"]
val FixAccronyms2 : aList:string list -> fixString:'a -> unit

>FixAccronyms2 myList2 "the us dollar in sc";;
NIF, NIF
PF, PF
PS, PS
SC, SC
US, US
USA, USA
USD, USD
val it : unit = ()
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one more way to do it:

```
open System
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let properCase lookup str =
    Regex.Replace(str, String.Join("|", Seq.map Regex.Escape lookup),
        (fun (x : Match) -> x.Value.ToUpper()),
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

The usage is the same as in @Daniel's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic

let properCase lookup (str: string) =
  let lookupDict = Dictionary(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
  for word in lookup do lookupDict.Add(word, word)
  (str, str.Split()) ||> Array.fold (fun pcWord word -> 
    match lookupDict.TryGetValue(word) with
    | true, s -> pcWord.Replace(word, s)
    | _ -> pcWord)

> properCase ["NIF"; "PF"; "PS"; "SC"; "US"; "USA"; "USD"] "The us dollar in sc"
val it : string = "The US dollar in SC"
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your responses!   I never imagined getting three unique methods for the same result.  And, none of you even came close to what I "thought" would be the answer.  I expected some sort of patter matching done by iterating through the list.

However, I ask you this: How could I have known about these libraries?  Is this just experience or is there a method with which I could find libraries or methods to solve a question?